# Recessed LED lights need to be turned on twice to work

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, led, dimmer-switch

I recently installed recessed LED lights in by basement.  On two of the three runs I have an issue that when I first turn on the lights some of the lights only produce a low dim, and don't react the the dimmer switch's level. However, if I turn the lights back off and then on again everything works perfectly.  This happens every time I use the lights.

Also when I first turn the lights off the lights give a quick burst of light before they turn off. However, this only happens when there is a light didn't isn't working properly, it doesn't do it after I turn them back on and all the lights work correctly.

I have switched out the dimmer switch to one that is compatible when the LED lights, but that didn't fix the problem.

The lights are Commercial Electric Easy-up canless LED recessed lights Model #CER407943k50wh.  The dimmer switch is Lutron Diva C.L. Model # dvcl-153p.  I have switched out the dimmer switch and that hasn't worked.  I've put in an non-dimmer switch and this fixed the problem, but I would like to have these lights be able to be dimmed.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. What make/model are the LEDs and the dimmer? Have you tried a simple switch rather than a dimmer? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Are these standard style Edison lamps? Try 1 normal lamp and see if they work. Not all dimming  LED’s work with led rated dimmers. Proof of this can be if a larger load (1 incandescent lamp) makes it work

Comment: you may have multimode LED light bulbs ... modes are changed by turning off-on

Comment: Noting your edit, the dimmer is on the [compatibility list](https://images.homedepot-static.com/catalog/pdfImages/7c/7cdae9d3-19ef-4382-917d-7d6a254f33ab.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

I recently added some canless LEDs on a multi-way switch with a dimmer and I noticed something interesting. If I have the dimmer set very low (near or at the lowest setting), the lights will not engage at all. Adjusting the dimmer to a higher brightness and switching them back on seems to work. I would try leaving the dimmer at least at 50% or higher and see if that fixes the problem (you can always dim them once they are on).

The catch with LED fixtures and LED dimmers is they aren't always compatible. Some even go so far as to list dimmers they work with, and will exclude supporting any others (even if they are LED compatible).